# How do I start a gaming group?

Tags: adnd-1e, group-dynamics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find other RPG players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players)

I would like to start an AD&D group at my local library. But how do I start one? How do I spread the word? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's an older question that may be of help here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players

Comment: Yeah, I think this one is pretty much a combined duplicate of http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players and http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/828/where-can-i-find-a-place-to-play.  I suggest closing as a duplicate of those, and if you have other specific questions not covered, open those.

Comment: @mxyzplk I disagree -- There's more to getting started than just finding the place and people. [Also, obligatory link to Strangedupe :)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: There is more, which should be split out into more specific questions. It's too broad and will get random answers.  The proof is in the pudding - those other questions got large numbers of answers, this one most people are staying away from because they smell the vague. Everything about the existing answer is in the answers to those other questions.

Comment: Aang, make sure you click the check mark to accept the best answer to all the old questions you've asked.  People like to know which answer you thought was best.

Comment: The record of answers here (one, which doesn't say anything not said in the 2 linked questions) proves to me this is a dupe. Closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three factors come to mind for me:

- Arrange for a place/time to play.
- Spread the word among your friends.
- Spread the word online.

#### Library

First you'll want to make sure the library is ok with you meeting there for a game.  Many libraries have rooms available for groups to meet, but they might be limited in purpose, and they'll certainly be limited in times that they're available.  Check with the library directly for more details.

#### Friends

Talk to your friends and see if anyone's interested in playing D&D.  If they're interested in the idea, but not available, have them pass the word along to *their* friends.  You probably know a lot of people, and those people know a lot more people.  Make use of Facebook for this part.

#### Online

If your social network doesn't do the trick, try looking online.  [Meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com/) has a good reputation for getting people together, though I've never tried it myself.  If you're in a major metropolitan area, there's probably someone with a site online for gamers in your region -- Google is your friend for this.

If you do end up getting people together from online, try and have at least one person you already know present at the game.  It's a lot easier to get everyone on the same page when one of them is already there.

And once you've gotten a group together, update your post and tell us what worked.  If you have this question, someone else will probably have it in the future.